# Short key in MyEclipse

Tags: java, intellij-idea, myeclipse

I used IntellJ idea for development to 2 past year but now using MyEclipse. I use `psvm + Tab` short key for generate `public static void main(String[] args)` method, I want know synonymous of this short key exist in MyEclipse? (I couldn't find or defined new short key in MyEclipse in `Preferences/General/Keys`)

Comment: sorry.I accepted .Thanks for your reminder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MyEclipse and also in Eclipse, `Ctrl+Spacebar` is used to view autocomplete suggestions. In your current class, just start to type "main", as you enter `m,a,...` letters, use `Ctrl + Spacebar` anytime to see suggestions/autocompleting options. You will find `main method` at the top of the list.

Another option is having checkbox of `public static void main(String[] args)` checked for the question of **"Which method stubs would you like to create?"** that is visible in the dialog window opening upon your "new class" creation event. Try it.

Comment: That also applies to Eclipse too (of which MyEclipse is a child of).

Comment: @MJM I supplied another choice for you, review my post please.

Comment: type `sop` and give `Ctrl + space` for another thing!

Comment: @Kaipa M Sarma  "sop"+Ctrl+Space don't generate my goal.(public static void main(String[] args))

Comment: i know, i showed another example where `Ctrl+Space` can be used. This is not for psvm.

Answer (score 1):

The wizard to create a new class offers the possibility to have a `public static void main(String[] args)` created inside the classes body. Just look at the checkboxes at the bottom of the wizards form.

Comment: Thanks, but in act I know in create time of class I can generate this method, I want generate this method in another time.